# Your favourite database client tool

Tags: database

Wondering what is the best or most popular database client tool.  Similar to Microsoft's SQL management studio, but one that can work with various databases.  Other tools I have found are:

- [Toad for SQL Server](http://www.toadsoft.com/toadsqlserver/toad_sqlserver.htm)
- [Database fishing tool](http://daft.sourceforge.net/)
- [Apex SQL Studio](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_univ_studio.asp)

Some of these tools can even compare and sync database schema's and some cases the data itself as well.  Very useful when deploying applications for example from a pre-production environment to production environment.

So what's your favourite database manager ?  Maybe there is a nice open source tool out there that is well rounded with the most useful features.

Comment: I think this is a valid programming related question, because during development you often want to see the database content from a neutral point of view and not through your application. It's a development tool like an editor or a debugger.

Comment: Thank you DR.  You put that in better terms, that is exactly why I wanted to ask this question here.  I make heavy use of this category of tools while developing and I just wanted to probe what else is out there and if there is one that people prefer more than others.

Comment: [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/). Great interface, actively developed open source, supports SSH tunneling and supports (almost?) every database, including NoSQL databases: MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, MariaDB, Cassandra, CSV files, Firebird, Mongo, DB2, Sqlite, etc etc etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)**

- Open source
- Works with many databases

Comment: -I chose this as the answer because it seems to be the best one for me right now, but I think other ones in this list are also very useful depending on what database you are working with.

Comment: Very cool...nice plugins, (e.g. refactoring) autocompletion on column names, the list goes on!  Only con -- written in Java ;)

Comment: it always freezes when I connect using ojdbc8 driver connec to Oracle 18c DB using oci.dll and from oracle instant client 19.3. Last query, executed by squirrel sql before hanging is: `select table as table_type from dual\nunion select 'VIEW' as table_type from dual\nunion select 'SYNONYM' as table_type from dual\n`. It happens before Editor window opens.

Answer (score 6):

SqlDbx - www.sqldbx.com - has a free edition, is portable  and works with quite a few dbs.

Also AnySQL Maestro - http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/anysql/maestro/

Answer (score 3):

I use **[PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html)**, as soon as I have to work on an Oracle Database. I like the UI, simple and fast.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Aqua Data Studio for many years now and it is the most valuable of all my tools - see [Aquafold](http://www.aquafold.com/)

Comment: Aqua is great but it also costs a bit if you need to get a copy to each member of your team.

Answer (score 2):

[DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/) - there's a free version with a bit limited functionality and a fully fledged one for $149.

Answer (score 2):

I use Navicat myself. It supports MySQL, PostgreSQL and Oracle.

Comment: I'm quite satisfied with its free version, Navicat Lite (http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Internet-Utilities/Navicat-Lite.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Developer is nice for Oracle and has plugins for several other databases.

> http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html

Comment: I use this as my one stop DB interface. I can get to any database I want from there. A bit of a resource hog, but I'll live.

Answer (score 2):

[Eclipse Data Tools Platform](http://www.iipt.fr/dtptutor.html) within Eclipse (my primary IDE):

- Open source, works with many databases
- Do all the basics and some advanced stuff. In recent versions you can find some kind of [visual query builder](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio-Eclipse/creating_and_executing_an_sql_query.htm) as well.
- Oracle has a [plugin](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14545_01/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.database.doc/html/gettingStarted/files/gettingStarted.html) where implemented some Oracle-specific functions.

Answer (score 2):

If your're using MS Sql Server, try using [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/); it's much more lightweight than the Management Studio, and you'll be practicing writing queries in linq in the meantime as well.

[image]
<sub>(source: [linqpad.net](http://www.linqpad.net/linqpadmed.png))</sub>

Comment: Interesting, i didn't know this existed.  This could really come handy.

Comment: +1 - great for running quick SQL queries, testing .NET code, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PostgreSQL (and, really, you should be!), [PgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) rocks. It lets you query, explore tables, do administrative tasks, manage users, visually explain complex queries, graphically build queries and much more. It runs on Windows, Linux and OS X and can connect to local or remote PostgreSQL servers.

Answer (score 1):

[SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) for MySQL.

[TOAD](http://www.toadsoft.com/toad_oracle.htm) for when I worked with Oracle.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I prefer...

- [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) for Oracle
- The inbuilt tool for MSSQL
- The inbuilt tool for DB2

Answer (score 1):

[RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/) - it works with pretty much any database you can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Any comments on [LyteRAD](http://www.lytecube.com/lyterad)? Not a pure database management tool, but good for creating and prototyping db apps quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Query Express](http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx) and it's great because it's actually a *standalone 100 KB file*, no installation needed. It only does querying but it's fast and free.

Answer (score -3):

If you need data comparison, schema comparison or visual query builder, than you should take a look at our [database tools for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/):

- [dbForge Schema Compare for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/schemacompare/)
- [dbForge Data Compare for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/datacompare/)
- [dbForge Query Builder for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/querybuilder/)

All these tools are quite affordable and have 30-days trial period.